# Iterative solution to find maximum element

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to solve the maximum code by iterative. I started by creating an array, can you help me to continue:

```
(do do-array (d l) 
  (setf b (make-array (length d)) 
  (do (((i=0)(temp d)) ((> i (- l 1)) (return)) 
  (setf (aref b i) (car temp)) 
  (setq i (+ i 1)) 
  (setq temp (cdr temp))))
```

Comment: Which dialect? Emacs Lisp, Common Lisp? Also, do you need to use a vector or you can use a list? Be specific.

Comment: Common lisp and i need to use a list

Comment: @PatyRizk The code in your question (aref, make-array) suggests that you want an array, but in the previous comment you say you want a list.  Then in [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815218/iterative-solution-to-find-maximum-element/26819111?noredirect=1#comment42213894_26819111) on a good answer you say you need to use an array.  Please clarify your question (use the edit link below the question).  Right now we don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: yep my mistake sorry;; i need to do first write an array then write a function to print the array example (5 4 7 1 9 3) and after a function to find the max in this array

Comment: What is `(i=0)` supposed to be? CL doesn't use `=` for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "iterative" as in "using built in iterative constructs", rather than "using constant stack space" because Common Lisp doesn't universally optimize tail calls. Something like

```
(loop for elem in my-list maximizing elem)
```

should do it for you. The important, but unspecified part of the problem is: what do you do with empty lists? The above returns `0`, but maybe you want to return `nil` or throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `loop`-based solution, here's something more verbose:

```
CL-USER> (defun my-max (lst)
           (let ((max (car lst)))
             (dolist (x (cdr lst) max)
               (when (> x max)
                 (setf max x)))))
MY-MAX
CL-USER> (my-max '())
NIL
CL-USER> (my-max '(1 2 3 -4))
3
```

Comment: I'd write `(dolist (x (cdr lst) max) ...)`; the third element in the first argument to `dolist` is a return value form.

Comment: Also, since `max` has to do the comparison, too, it might be better to just `(setf max (max max x))`.

Comment: Actually, with those two things, and making max an aux variable, you get [a fairly concise version](http://pastebin.com/zrjCvdj0): `(defun my-max (list &aux (max (first list))) (dolist (x (rest list) max) (setf max (max x max))))`

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, you're right about return value of `dolist`. However, `max` is just name of a variable and there is only one comparison.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misread it as `(when (> x max) (setf x (max x max)))`;  I'm not sure why

Comment: i need to use the array to find the max..

Comment: what i want to do first write an array then write a function to print the array example (5 4 7 1 9 3) and after a function to find the max in this array ..

Comment: @PatyRizk In the question you used aref, which suggested an array, but then in a comment you specifically said you wanted a *list*: ["i need to use a list"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815218/iterative-solution-to-find-maximum-element/26819111?noredirect=1#comment42205357_26815218)